# Text File "file not found' error in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

[image]

So in Delphi 10.3, I'm trying to do an exercise with inserting an element into an array(I'm still in high school and I'm revising this for our test on Thursday). My problem is that I'm trying to insert a text file's content into an array **but I constantly get a 'file not found' error** for the text file (even though it's in the same folder than my code and everything). I also attached the code I'm using/trying to use to solve it. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Always use an absolute path. If you know that the file is located in the same directory as the EXE, its fully-qualified file name is `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Gardens.txt'`. Notice that by default, the EXE isn't placed in the same folder as the source code (but in a subdirectory).

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Should I add this (ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Gardens.txt') in the AssignFile function ?

Comment: Yes, that should be the second argument (the file name). But it will only work if the text file indeed is located in the same directory as the EXE file.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand   AssignFile(tGarden,ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Gardens.txt')  ,like that and also should the exe name of the program be in the Application.ExeName argument,like frmLOL.exe for example?

Comment: Yes and no, respectively; it should be exactly as it is. `Application.ExeName` contains the fully-qualified file name of the executable (EXE file), e.g., `C:\MyApp\myapp.exe`. `ExtractFilePath` is a function that takes a file name and returns the directory of it, so `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)` might be `C:\MyApp\ `. Hence `ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + 'Gardens.txt'` might be `C:\MyApp\Gardens.txt`. But you could have found this out by yourself by trying it! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Oh ok, that makes more sense because I thought you had to put in an exe name until I started poking around myself and realized that made no sense, so I wanted to make sure. :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand  ok we did it, we got the text file working. Thank you so much, man! I should ask you every time I struggle with this stuff (you've helped me more than my teacher ever would/did, lol).Thanks again for the help!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Please do not post images of code. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Code is text that can be easily copied and pasted directly into your question and formatted so that it's easily readable. Thanks.

Comment: You are not displaying the entire array. On your read-in the first line read is stored in arrGardenAddress[0] (from iCount:=0 outside the WHILE loop), but in Display you are looping from index 1 (ONE) through iCount-1, thereby skipping index 0. Without knowing the exact definition of arrGardenAddress, I cannot see exactly where the actual error is located (what are the minimum and maximum indices of the array in your definition?)